# receiving order details and payment confirmation (e-commerce site)

Tags: php, html, mysql, paypal, e-commerce

I'm a newbie developer working on my first site. I created a login environment for both regular users and admins as well. The admins are able to see pages that regular user cannot. I have created the shopping cart (PHP) which adds up all the selected items. I am not sure how to proceed now. I know I have to use PayPal but I am unsure where to start. I also don't know how the client would receive a customer's order. Would this happen through notifications that he would be able to see on the admin page? Or would the details go to his email address? Also how would payment confirmation be received? I would really appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't delete any records. Just use [Pagination](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html) and sort the payment confirmation from recent payment to oldest i.e. in Descending order of payment Date and Time. Also provide an option for your client to fetch records based on time range, even though its optional, it'll make your client happy. If you want more clarification regarding paypal integration, refer [**this**](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration).

Answer (score 1):

> I know I have to use PayPal but I am unsure where to start.

Check out their website for their API and code snippets.

> I also don't know how the client would receive a customer's order. Would this happen through notifications that he would be able to see on the admin page? Or would the details go to his email address?

Do both and make it an option for the admins to choose.

> Also how would payment confirmation be received?

Same as above.

Comment: Thanks. If the confirmations appear on the admin page, should I set them up to delete after a certain amount of time? I'm assuming there is a way to do this with PHP or MySQL

Comment: I don't think you should keep the notifications once the admin saw them, unless they are related to some action to be performed, in which case they should be removed once the action is done. Does this make sense?

Comment: Also I agree that you should never delete a record. Keep everything around, and mark them as "deleted" if they should not come up in your regular queries. Then, every fiscal year (or a multiple of that if necessary) do an archive of past records (ie. move them out to archive tables to keep the work tables queries snappy).